# HTML onmouseover Event position of popup

Tags: css

I have this code to create a popup on `mouseover`.

```
<a
  href=""
  onmouseover="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='img/voorbeeld_prefix_dxf.jpg';"
  onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='';"
>
  <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
  <img src="" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute"
/></a>
```

[image]

How to make the popup image appaer above the button?
Like:
[image]

Comment: Hi, your second image looks the same as the first one.

Comment: Correct, only the position is different.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not understanding. What position is different?

Comment: Does OP want the popup should appear above the button of the `question mark`?

Comment: That is correct @PennyLiu

Answer (score 0):

Might be not a clever solution but perhaps we can adjust it by using transform CSS property like this:

```js
function showImg() {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100';
}

function hideImg() {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').src = '';
}
```

```css
section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.image-panel {
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

#placeholder {
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">

<section>
  <a href="" onmouseover="showImg(this)" onmouseout="hideImg(this)">
    <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
    <div class="image-panel">
      <img src="" id="placeholder" />
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```